# Universal Android Objects Style for All Android Versions?

Tags: java, android, object, styles, version

In Android Studio, the objects style are different for different Android OS Versions.

If there's a green button on Lollipop it is okay. But on Android 4.3 (example) they are gray. Why? How can I make a universal style?

Example Lollipop/Marshmallow: [Here](http://postimg.org/image/legv77abt/)

Example Android 4.3: [Here](http://postimg.org/image/526thgw09/)

Edit: Of course I tried it on a real device with Android 4.3. I'm not talking only of the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create a style for the button
here an example [custom button style](https://www.androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=3307)

Comment: I preferred the code written here, but I'm happy even a simple link. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must create your own style and use it.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```